# Ajax Tabs with PHP sites

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tabs

I have a "little" big problem with my web application. 
First, I must confess, that I am not so good in english :).

I have realize very simple html+css-Tabs based on ajax (powered by jquery) and each Tab request a separate PHP-site. Every site includes min. one form with php-values and other jquery-effects/-plugins.

The primary problem is the form-view in every tab. The ajax-loaded forms were shown not complete and other form were complete blank. I locate the problem and delete PHP-code in one of some fieldsets and finaly I show this one fieldset and the rest of the form were blank.

If I use only css-based tabs and without ajax functionality the forms loaded completely.

What is the problem with ajax? I dont understand it :P

Here is a part of one of the forms:

```
 <form action="#" method="post" name="form_project" class="form_project mainform">
    <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="<?= issetGlobals('uid') ?>" />
    <table border="0" id="tbl-projects" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox" name="cb_newProject" onclick="actFieldset('#fs-newProject')" /> <label for="cb_newProject">Projekt erstellen</label></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>

            <fieldset id="fs-newProject" disabled="disabled"><legend>Projektverzeichnis erstellen</legend>
                <table border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="projectName">Projektname</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="projectName" value="" /></td>
                    </tr><tr>
                        <td><label for="projectManager">Projektleiter</label></td>
                        <td><select size="1" name="projectManager" id="projectManager">
                        <?php
                            foreach($DBma->getEmployees() as $value) {
                                if($value['uid'] == issetGlobals('uid'))
                                    echo '<option value="'.$value["uid"].'" selected="selected">'. convertString($value["name"]) .'</option>';
                                else
                                    echo '<option value="'.$value["uid"].'">'. convertString($value["name"]) .'</option>';
                            }
                        ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

And here the "converted" JS-Code:

```
$('#tabs-nav li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        Tab($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});

function Tab(key){
    $('#tabs-nav li').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    $(key).addClass('active');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'tab-content.php?tab=' + key,
        type: 'get',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(key + '-loading').html('<img src=\'images/ajax-loader.gif\' width=\'16\' height=\'16\' alt=\'Loading\' />');
        }
    }).done(function(responseText)  {
            $(key + '-loading').html("");
            $('#tabs-content').html(responseText);
        });
}
```

Comment: As you know there a working ajax form solutions. So without knowing what you did it is kind of hard to tell whats wrong with your code ;)

Comment: I think with ajax load of the page it is not loading/executing the javascript on the other page. You may have to load and execute them explicitly. And your question does not contain enough data to solve it. Post some code.

Comment: For example, the last one "experiment" I used the script:
http://jonplante.com/blog/accessible-ajax-tabs-with-mootools

But I convert the mootools-code in jquery-code.